# Graph in Latex using Tikz and PGFplots

Tags: latex, tikz, pgfplots

How to draw this graph in LaTeX? I have used Ti*k*Z but I can't get it done exactly.

[image: A graph to be drawn in Latex]

This is what I have tried so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-1]
   \tkzAxeXY
   \draw[thick] (6,3) -- (-4,5);
   \filldraw[black] (6,3) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west] {A(6,3)};
   \filldraw[black] (-4,5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=east] {B(-4,5)};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Output Pic]

Comment: Can you post what you tried?

Comment: @Eddymage please check my new post

Comment: You should modify your question, not posting your attempts as an answer.

Comment: Ok.. I have edited the post

Comment: Where did the output pic come from? It does not really match the code. Also, which library are you using (commands tkzInit, tkzAxeXY...)?

Comment: Can you please make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: I only used this package \usepackage{tkz-euclide}

Answer (score 1):

Using regular pgfplots you could do the following: Draw the line with the points you choose and label them with nodes. Then draw the additional distance markers using `\draw` in the axis coordinate system (The concrete positions of all elements may have to be adjusted).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tiny
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 6cm,
        height = 4cm,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ymin=-1,
        ymax=7,
        xmin=-6,
        xmax=6,
        xtick distance=1,
        ytick distance=1,
        axis y line*=center,
        axis x line*=center,        
        enlarge x limits=.12
    ]
\addplot+[sharp plot] coordinates {(6,3) (1,4) (-4,5) } node[below=1mm, pos=0] {A(6,3)}
    node[pos=0.45,below=1mm] {P(x,y)}
    node[pos=1,below=1mm] {B(-4,5)};

\draw[|-|] (axis cs:1.2,5) -- node [above, rotate=-10] {m=13} (axis cs:6.3,3.9);   
\draw[|-|] (axis cs:-3.8,6) -- node [above, rotate=-10, pos=.3] {n=2} (axis cs:1.2,5);   
   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: out pic]